# Can't make it a list - python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I searched for and answer and I couldn't find an answer.

I can't make that str to a list
how can I print it as a list?

please advice.

```
punctuation = ['.','(',')','?',':',':',',','.','!','/','"',"'",'@','#','$','%','^','&','*']
tokenize = str(input("Please enter a sentence " ))
tokenize = "".join(char for char in tokenize if char not in punctuation)
print ("Tokenized:",tokenize.lower())
```

Comment: What's the problem? This doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: Are you trying to make `tokenize.lower()` a list? `list(tokenize.lower())`

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] (edit it into your question); your description of what you want is not at all clear, but even a simple example input, expected output, and actual output would make things much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` with an alternation pattern:

```
import re
punctuation = ['.','(',')','?',':',':',',','.','!','/','"',"'",'@','#','$','%','^','&','*']
tokenize = str(input("Please enter a sentence: " ))
print(re.split('|'.join(map(re.escape, punctuation)), tokenize))
```

Sample input and output:

```
Please enter a sentence: Hello,World!foo:bar
['Hello', 'World', 'foo', 'bar']
```